# How add parametr to URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I would like add ?dev=1 to every link in react-router-dom.

I tried replace:

```
    var href = history.createHref(location);
    return _react2.default.createElement("a", _extends({}, props, { onClick: this.handleClick, href: href, ref: innerRef }));
```

to

```
    var href = history.createHref(location);
    href = process.env.IS_MAINTANCE_MODE ? href + '?dev=1' : href
    return _react2.default.createElement("a", _extends({}, props, { onClick: this.handleClick, href: href, ref: innerRef }));
```

Its not working, parametr dev is display in elemnent a, but onClick its redirect to link without parametr.

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but you forgot to close the second row `;` . Also can you try printing `process.env.IS_MAINTANCE_MODE` to make sure it is not `false`?

Comment: You do not need to put ; in Javascript at the end.

Comment: Yes, IS_MAINTANCE_MODE is set true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solved. I correct add ?dev=1 as parametr to link but I didn't change redirect.

Full code component Link from react-router-dom

```
"use strict";

exports.__esModule = true;

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var _react = require("react");

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _propTypes = require("prop-types");

var _propTypes2 = _interopRequireDefault(_propTypes);

var _invariant = require("invariant");

var _invariant2 = _interopRequireDefault(_invariant);

var _history = require("history");

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _objectWithoutProperties(obj, keys) { var target = {}; for (var i in obj) { if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue; if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue; target[i] = obj[i]; } return target; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var isModifiedEvent = function isModifiedEvent(event) {
  return !!(event.metaKey || event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey);
};

/**
 * The public API for rendering a history-aware <a>.
 */

var Link = function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(Link, _React$Component);

  function Link() {
    var _temp, _this, _ret;

    _classCallCheck(this, Link);

    for (var _len = arguments.length, args = Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
      args[_key] = arguments[_key];
    }

    return _ret = (_temp = (_this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _React$Component.call.apply(_React$Component, [this].concat(args))), _this), _this.handleClick = function (event) {
      if (_this.props.onClick) _this.props.onClick(event);

      if (!event.defaultPrevented && // onClick prevented default
      event.button === 0 && // ignore everything but left clicks
      !_this.props.target && // let browser handle "target=_blank" etc.
      !isModifiedEvent(event) // ignore clicks with modifier keys
      ) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var history = _this.context.router.history;
          var _this$props = _this.props,
              replace = _this$props.replace,
              to = _this$props.to;


          if (replace) {
            history.replace(process.env.IS_MAINTENCE_MODE ? `${to}?dev=1` : to);
          } else {
            history.push(process.env.IS_MAINTENCE_MODE ? `${to}?dev=1` : to);
          }
        }
    }, _temp), _possibleConstructorReturn(_this, _ret);
  }

  Link.prototype.render = function render() {
    var _props = this.props,
        replace = _props.replace,
        to = _props.to,
        innerRef = _props.innerRef,
        props = _objectWithoutProperties(_props, ["replace", "to", "innerRef"]); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

    (0, _invariant2.default)(this.context.router, "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>");

    (0, _invariant2.default)(to !== undefined, 'You must specify the "to" property');

    var history = this.context.router.history;

    var location = typeof to === "string" ? (0, _history.createLocation)(to, null, null, history.location) : to;

    var href = history.createHref(location);
    href = process.env.IS_MAINTENCE_MODE ? `${href}?dev=1` : href;
    return _react2.default.createElement("a", _extends({}, props, { onClick: this.handleClick, href: href, ref: innerRef }));
  };

  return Link;
}(_react2.default.Component);

Link.propTypes = {
  onClick: _propTypes2.default.func,
  target: _propTypes2.default.string,
  replace: _propTypes2.default.bool,
  to: _propTypes2.default.oneOfType([_propTypes2.default.string, _propTypes2.default.object]).isRequired,
  innerRef: _propTypes2.default.oneOfType([_propTypes2.default.string, _propTypes2.default.func])
};
Link.defaultProps = {
  replace: false
};
Link.contextTypes = {
  router: _propTypes2.default.shape({
    history: _propTypes2.default.shape({
      push: _propTypes2.default.func.isRequired,
      replace: _propTypes2.default.func.isRequired,
      createHref: _propTypes2.default.func.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  }).isRequired
};
exports.default = Link;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the location beforehand:

```
let location = {
    pathname: `/{YourRoute}}`,
    query: {dev: '1'})
};
let href = history.createHref(location);
return _react2.default.createElement("a", _extends({}, props, { onClick: this.handleClick, href: href, ref: innerRef }));
```